# ¿Cómo agregar un datarow en la primera posición de un dataset?

Tags: c#, webforms

Tengo una función que consulta con la base de datos, es la siguiente:

```
Public DataSet obtenerListadoCategoriaFiltro()
    {

        DataSet data = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            SqlConnection s = conn.Connection;
            SqlDataAdapter datos;
            com.Connection = s;
            com.CommandText = "GET_listCategoria";
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            datos = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            datos.Fill(data);

                    DataRow a = data.Tables[0].NewRow();
                    a["folio"] = 0;
                    a["nombre"] = "Selecciona una categoria";
                    data.Tables[0].Rows.Add(a);

        }
        finally
        {
            com.Connection.Close();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Pero el dataRow `a` al final termina siendo la última fila, quisiera que sea la primera fila. Estoy programando en .net c#

Comment: :'( when todos te ignoran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No intentes hacer eso.

Ese elemento "Selecciona una categoria" realmente le pertenece a la interfaz de usuario, sea el cliente que sea, diferentes frameworks tienen manera de añadir esta opción al conjunto de valores mostrados en el control en el que se vaya a mostrar los datos.

Por otro lado ¿Realmente necesitas que el método devuelva un `DataSet`?.

En todo caso debería devolver solo un `DataTable`, o mejor aún una colección de una clase personalizada.

> **Actualización**: Ya que el framework usado es ASP.NET Webforms, lo mejor como ya mencioné antes sería insertar el elemento a nivel de UI, y no en la función mencionada en la pregunta

Suponiendo que tu `DropDownList` se llama `ddlCategorias` puedes insertar el elmento inicial llamando al método `Insert` de la propiedad `Items` del `DropDownList`

```
ddlCategorias.DataBind(); // Después de hacer bind
ddlCategorias.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Selecciona una categoria", "0"));
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Carlos, pues con ese dataset lleno un DropDownList, es más eficaz un datatable?

Comment: Un `DataSet` representa un conjunto de tablas en memoria, Un `DataTable` representa a una sola tabla que es lo que quieres mostrar en el DropDownList. Aún mejor sería devolver un IEnumerable<T> donde T es una clase personalizada con las propiedades que correspondan a las columnas de tu tabla que desees mostrar.

Comment: Estás usando asp.net webforms?

Comment: Si estoy usando web forms

Comment: Ya actualizé la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias Carlos, ahora ya entiendo mejor, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puede intentar añadiendo la fila al inicio, es decir indice cero empleando el método [InsertAt(fila,index)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datarowcollection.insertat(v=vs.110).aspx) , aunque mejor sería que su método retorne un `DataTable` directamente y no un `DateSet`

```
DataRow a = data.Tables[0].NewRow();
a["folio"] = 0;
a["nombre"] = "Selecciona una categoria";
data.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(a,0);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Joel, pero por qué es mejor un dataTable?

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez llegué tarde pero lo principal sería la optimización (memoria) , sería quizá conveniente usar `DataSet` si trabajas  con más de una tabla pero si es solo una , es innecesario.

Comment: No te preocupes Joel y gracias por la observación